# How to parse SubjectDirectoryAttributes Extension with OpenSSL?

Tags: c++, openssl, certificate, x509

How can I read the X509 Certificate Extension: Subject Directory Attributes with OpenSSL in C++?

My Certificate contains the SubjectDirectoryAttributes-Extension with the following Attributes:

```
OID                                       : Value
-------------------------------------------------------------------
(1.3.6.1.5.5.7.9.4) countryOfCitizenship  : DE
(1.3.6.1.5.5.7.9.3) gender                : F
(1.3.6.1.5.5.7.9.1) dateOfBirth           : 1971-10-14 12:00:00 UTC
(1.3.6.1.5.5.7.9.2) placeOfBirth          : Darmstadt
```

So i want to get these pairs of OID and Value.

I found no Struct like SUBJECT_DIRECTORY_ATTRIBUTES in the Source-Code I can use. I got the Extension this way:

```
int loc = X509_get_ext_by_NID(certificate, NID_subject_directory_attributes, -1);
X509_EXTENSION *ex = X509_get_ext(certificate, loc);
```

But how can I get then all the data, which means all the OIDs and Values to the OIDs? The ASN.1 Structure is:

```
SubjectDirectoryAttributes ::= Attributes

Attributes ::= SEQUENCE SIZE (1..MAX) OF Attribute

Attribute ::= SEQUENCE 
{
    type AttributeType 
    values SET OF AttributeValue 
}

AttributeType ::= OBJECT IDENTIFIER
AttributeValue ::= ANY DEFINED BY AttributeType
```

I found out that I get a custom extension with: `X509_EXTENSION_get_object(ex)` and that the OpenSSL-Type `X509_NAME_ENTRY` is the equvivalent to the ASN.1-Structure `Attribute` resp. `AttributeTypeAndValue`.
So i tried to cast the result of `X509_EXTENSION_get_data(ex)` to a `STACK_OF(X509_NAME_ENTRY)` and to `X509_NAME`. But `X509_NAME` is the same as `STACK_OF(X509_NAME_ENTRY)`.

Then I tried to get the number of attributes by calling the `sk_X509_NAME_ENTRY_num()` function on the `STACK_OF(X509_NAME_ENTRY)` resp. `X509_NAME.entries`, but I got not the right number.
I expect to get the number 3 or 4 (don't know the exactly internal counting - but the example cert contains 4 Attributes, so the output should be 3 or 4 depending if the counting will start at 0 or 1).
But instead of 3 or 4 I got a much larger number like 34335029 and this number is different every time I run the code. So I think there is a problem with the casting or I did not choose the right Data-Type(s).

I'm using OpenSSL 1.0.2j.

So what's wrong and how can I fix it?

Here a short excerpt of my code:

```
X509_EXTENSION *ex = ....

STACK_OF(X509_NAME_ENTRY) *st = (STACK_OF(X509_NAME_ENTRY)*) X509_EXTENSION_get_data(ex);
printf(sk_X509_NAME_ENTRY_num(st));

// or alternative

X509_Name *name = (X509_Name*) X509_EXTENSION_get_data(ex);
printf(sk_X509_NAME_ENTRY_num(name.entries));
```

Here I append the certificate if you need it. It's from the RFC specification:

```
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----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-----END CERTIFICATE-----
```

Comment: Also see [C++ How to parse Subject Directory Attributes Extension?](https://mta.openssl.org/pipermail/openssl-users/2017-May/005811.html) on the OpenSSL users mailing list.

Comment: This post in the Mailinglist is done by me. But i don't know how to do it like the way the OpenSSL team has done it with the GENERAL_NAMES. So anyone there who could help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since OpenSSL has no direct support in the crypto libary there is no built in code for parsing this extension. I have either to wait for official support or implement the whole thing by myself.